# RouteLink with dynamic parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I'm trying to store routes in database, and list those based on parameters.

Kinda like:

Route = "NewsDetail"

ParamKey 1 = "NewsID"

ParamVal 1 = "4"

....     2..3

And I would like to know how I create those routeparameters for the link...

```
<%= Html.RouteLink("Somename", "NewsDetali", new { newsID = Model.News.NewsID, headline = Model.News.Headline })%>
```

is there some way to pass those parameters dynamicallly?

/M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you could do. As always start with a model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller action populate this model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyModel
    {
        // TODO: Fetch those values from your database
        Values = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "NewsID", "4" },
            { "Headline", "foo bar" },
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

And finally in your view:

```
<%= Html.RouteLink("Somename", "NewsDetali", 
    new RouteValueDictionary(Model.Values)
) %>
```